# Identifier 'input' must be declared - PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Every time I run this and add as an input the words 'yellow' or 'red' or 'blue', the same error appears.

```
set serveroutput on
undefine color1
undefine color2
accept color1 prompt 'Type the 1st primary color: '
accept color2 prompt 'Type the 2nd primary color: '
begin
   if &color1 = &color2 then
      dbms_output.put_line(&color1||' plus '||&color2||' then '||&color1);
   elsif (&color1 = 'red' and &color2 = 'blue') or (&color2 = 'red' and &color1 = 'blue') then
      dbms_output.put_line(&color1||' plus '||&color2||' is purple');
   elsif (&color1 = 'red' and &color2 = 'yellow') or (&color2 = 'red' and &color1 = 'yellow') then
      dbms_output.put_line(&color1||' plus '||&color2||' is orange');
   else
      dbms_output.put_line(&color1||' plus '||&color2||' is green');
   end if;
end;
/
```

ERROR:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'BLUE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Please Help! :)

Comment: Did you try `accept color1 char prompt 'Type the 1st primary color: '?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
set serveroutput on
undefine color1
undefine color2
accept color1 prompt 'Type the 1st primary color: '
accept color2 prompt 'Type the 2nd primary color: '
BEGIN
   IF '&color1' = '&color2' THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('&color1'||' plus '||'&color2'||' then '||'&color1');
   elsif ('&color1' LIKE 'red' AND '&color2' LIKE 'blue') OR ('&color2' LIKE 'red' AND '&color1' LIKE 'blue') THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('&color1'||' plus '||'&color2'||' is purple');
   elsif ('&color1' LIKE 'red' AND '&color2' LIKE 'yellow') OR ('&color2' LIKE 'red' AND '&color1' LIKE 'yellow') THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('&color1'||' plus '||'&color2'||' is orange');
   ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('&color1'||' plus '||'&color2'||' is green');
   end if;
END;
/
```

Or it would be be better to store the color1 & color2 in a local variable like this,

```
SET serveroutput ON
undefine color1
undefine color2
accept color1 prompt 'Type the 1st primary color: '
accept color2 prompt 'Type the 2nd primary color: '
DECLARE 
   color_1 VARCHAR2(10) := '&color1';
   color_2 VARCHAR2(10) := '&color2';
BEGIN
   IF color_1 = color_2 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(color_1||' plus '||color_2||' then '||color_1);
   elsif (color_1 LIKE 'red' AND color_2 LIKE 'blue') OR (color_2 LIKE 'red' AND color_1 LIKE 'blue') THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(color_1||' plus '||color_2||' is purple');
   elsif (color_1 LIKE 'red' AND color_2 LIKE 'yellow') OR (color_2 LIKE 'red' AND color_1 LIKE 'yellow') THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(color_1||' plus '||color_2||' is orange');
   ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line(color_1||' plus '||color_2||' is green');
   END IF;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

`&color1` is a substitution variable, sqlplus basically replaces `&color1` with user input contents - which has to be a single-quoted literal here. As long as it is not, your `blue` input is treated as a variable name, which is not defined.

So, you have two options - either to input quoted `'blue'`, `'yellow'` etc. in sqlplus, or to replace `&color1` with `'&color1'` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 set serveroutput on
    undefine color1
    undefine color2
    accept color1 prompt 'Type the 1st primary color: '
    accept color2 prompt 'Type the 2nd primary color: '
    begin
       if '&color1' = '&color2' then
          dbms_output.put_line('&color1'||' plus '||'&color2'||' then '||'&color1');
       elsif ('&color1' like 'red' and '&color2' like 'blue') or ('&color2' like 'red' and '&color1' like 'blue') then
          dbms_output.put_line('&color1'||' plus '||'&color2'||' is purple');
       elsif ('&color1' like 'red' and '&color2' like 'yellow') or ('&color2' like 'red' and '&color1' like 'yellow') then
          dbms_output.put_line('&color1'||' plus '||'&color2'||' is orange');
       else
          dbms_output.put_line('&color1'||' plus '||'&color2'||' is green');
       end if;
    end;
    /
```